# Plugins page inside CP Settings not working

Tags: plugins, error-message, php

I get an error when trying to access CP/Settings/Plugins:

Fatal error: Class 'Craft\PluginVariable' not found in folderpath/craft/app/variables/PluginsVariable.php on line 47

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like an FTP upload or an unzipping operation didn't finish properly.

Try downloading a fresh copy of Craft from http://buildwithcraft.com and replacing the old `craft/app` folder with the new one.